# Getting google not defined errors possibly because of asynchronous load of Google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

I have two Javascript loads in my jsp page, the first loading the google maps API and the 2nd that loads a JS file that calls google.maps.OverlayView. The reference to google fails clearly because of the asynchronous load of the googleapis, but even if I remove async and defer, the problem persists. Can someone recommend a way around this?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
      pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey>"> 
</script>

 <!-- This file uses Google APIs --> 
 <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/InfoBox.js"/>">
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<script> 
//This is the callback function after Google Maps API loads
function initMap() {
    var container=document.getElementById("map");
    var anantapur = {lat: 14.68, lng: 77.6};

    var mapOptions = {
        styles: mapStyle,
        zoom: 6,
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 10,
        center: anantapur
    };
    var newMap = new google.maps.Map(container, mapOptions);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above will cause the error 'google not defined' at the line inside InfoBox.js that uses a google maps object.

In general, if I can only load Google APIs script asynchronously, how do I include other script files that use Google API objects?

Comment: Can't you just load the second file in a call back after the first load?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly this - I loaded the 2nd file dynamically in the callback and it worked. I am new to javascript and was not familiar with dynamic loading and found how to do it right here in stackflow.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Chris Hawkes, I loaded the 2nd file dynamically in the callback function and it worked.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
      pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey>" async defer >
</script>

</head>
<body>
<script>
function loadScript(url)
{
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = url;
}

//This is the callback function after Google Maps API loads
function initMap() {
    var container=document.getElementById("map");
    var anantapur = {lat: 14.68, lng: 77.6};

    //dynamic load of script file that uses google api objects
    loadScript("<c:url value="/resources/js/InfoBox.js"/>"); 

    var mapOptions = {
        styles: mapStyle,
        zoom: 6,
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 10,
        center: anantapur
    };
    var newMap = new google.maps.Map(container, mapOptions);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```